# Running Timer in iPhone Sleep mode (with no javascript)?

Tags: iphone

So as I have learned today, if I put a phone in sleep mode that is running a javascript timer function, it will become paused.

As I need a timer for a certain application - that needs to continue to record the time and display it, updating the innerHTML of an element ever second: how do you think I should go about getting this timer to work?

Thanks for the grand help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var startTime;
var timer;

function displayTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = new Date(now - startTime); // constructor uses UTC, so use UTC date functions from here on
    var hours = timeDiff.getUTCHours();
    var mins = (timeDiff.getUTCMinutes() < 10) ? '0' + timeDiff.getUTCMinutes() : timeDiff.getUTCMinutes();
    var secs = (timeDiff.getUTCSeconds() < 10) ? '0' + timeDiff.getUTCSeconds() : timeDiff.getUTCSeconds();
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs;
    if (hours >= 2) clearInterval(timer);
}

window.onload = function() {
    startTime = new Date();
    timer = setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
}
```

When the phone wakes and the app goes back to foreground, `startTime` should still be the original time when you started counting, so you just need to know the diff between now and then. It doesn't need to update the display while asleep; it just needs to know the time since the original starting time.

Comment: So, I had this arrangement before but am failing to see how to pass the logic into using your method:

function timer()
{
 
    var digiformat = "";
 if(i>3599)
 { var H = Math.floor(i/3600);
  var H = Math.floor(i/3600);
 }
 else
 {
  var H = 0;
 }
 
 var M = i - (H*3600)
 
 if(M>59)
 {
  M = Math.floor(M/60)
 }
 else
 {
  M = 0
 } 
 var S = i - (M*60) 
 if(H<10)
 {
  H = "0"+H;
 }
 if(M<10)
 {
  M = "0"+M;
 }
 if(S<10)
 {
  S = "0"+S;
 }
 document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = H+":"+M+":"+S;
    exe = setTimeout('timer()', 1000);
    i++;
 if(H>=2){
  clearTimeout(exe);
 } 
}

Comment: @Ben - no problem, hope this helps. I've updated the example to parse `timeDiff` for display.