# How to run JavaScript event when the iPad's screen is locked?

Tags: javascript, ipad, dom-events, mobile-safari

I am developing an alarm in HTML5 for iPad, but I noticed that when the screen goes into standby (or is blocked by the user), Safari blocks all events. I tried `setTimeout()`.

How to solve?

I just need to refresh the page or run a `.mp3` after a certain period of time.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Safari goes to sleep when the device is in sleep mode.

[Running Timer in iPhone Sleep mode (with no javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048192/running-timer-in-iphone-sleep-mode-with-no-javascript)

Comment: Maybe there is a way on jailbroken devices.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a native app for this, AFAIK.